# Send form by email in android without using email client apps

Tags: android, email

Someone, knows or knows a tutorial of how to send a form by email in android, without using the mail clients installed in the device, only that they are sent without the user having to go through this tedious task. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the amazon simple email service. It allows you to send email directly within your Android app without the need to trigger an email client.